# Home Assistant on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: smart-home, raspberry-pi

I tried to install Home Assistant on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, following this [blog post](https://www.home-assistant.io/blog/2017/05/01/home-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-zero-in-30-minutes/). 
I followed all steps, including starting the daemon as needed. 
WiFi is connected, and accessible via ‘ssh’

After 30 minutes, verified using ‘htop’ that update process has ended, I tried to connect using another PC - with no luck.

Can someone tell if additional processes are needed in order to run it?

> EDIT1:

```
pi@hassbian:/home/homeassistant $ sudo systemctl status home-assistant@homeassistant.service 
● home-assistant@homeassistant.service - Home Assistant for homeassistant
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/home-assistant@homeassistant.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-09-03 20:45:07 UTC; 17h ago
  Process: 631 ExecStart=/srv/homeassistant/bin/hass (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 631 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 03 20:45:07 hassbian systemd[1]: Started Home Assistant for homeassistant.
Sep 03 20:45:07 hassbian systemd[1]: home-assistant@homeassistant.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 03 20:45:07 hassbian systemd[1]: Unit home-assistant@homeassistant.service entered failed state.
pi@hassbian:/home/homeassistant $
```

> EDIT2:

```
pi@hassbian:/home/homeassistant $ sudo journalctl -u install_homeassistant.service
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-09-03 20:44:51 UTC, end at Tue 2018-09-04 17:14:54 UTC. --
```

> EDIT 3: new install of [version 1.4](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/installation/hassbian/)
>   first link referred to v1.3 ( as noted in post that suites to RPI zero ). After installing up-to-date software (v1.4), system is operting as needed.

Comment: What does it look like when you run `sudo systemctl status home-assistant@homeassistant.service`? You can [edit] to add the output to the bottom of your post.

Comment: As you suspected, it looks like the service running Home Assistant failed and it stopped running for some reason. Can you try running `sudo journalctl -u install_homeassistant.service` and editing in the results? That command should give you the log for the installer so we can see if anything went wrong there.

Comment: @Aurora0001 see edit2

Comment: solved : see edit 3

Comment: @Aurora0001 I was thinking how to formally answer it ( or edit my own Q ). thanks for you help :)

Comment: Please do answer it, as that will help others who read the question in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing latest version,[version 1.4](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/installation/hassbian/) , solved it.